# second attribute android:fitsSystemWindows="true" is ignored

Tags: android

when using `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` two times on frameLayout the second 
`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` is ignored and i get the result displayed in the image. i was expecting the second frame layout to be fitted same as the first one not going under the navigationbar or statusbar. why is that so?
[image]
layout that i used:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and activity style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Request to apply the given window insets to your second view. you need to do that right after it's applied.

```
ViewCompat.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(View view, WindowInsetsCompat insets)
```

so set follow listener to your first view.

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(View v, OnApplyWindowInsetsListener listener)
```